# Contour plot of a dataframe : Error occurs at Z dimension

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, contour

While making a filled contour plot from a pandas dataframe, the following error occurs every time. I have cross checked the dimension of Z which is 2-D, still the error occurs.

```
TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D
```

```
data = {'10.2': [72,57,56,67,69,136], '10.6':[31,23,19,17,41,74],
        '10.9': [27,96,97,99,18,40], '11.3':[10,98,100,35,67,258], '11.8':[124,92,49,24,88,209]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#### Create a meshgrid from the DataFrame index and columns

x = df.index
y = df.columns
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = df.values
c = plt.contourf([X, Y], Z)

TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D

#### Cross check the dimension of Z 

Z.ndim # it shows 2
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong or how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature is either `contourf(Z)` or `contourf(X, Y, Z)`. The `[X,Y,]` notation of the documentation is confusing, but means that you can pass those if you want. But because you actually put it in brackets, you created a 3D array which matplotlib was interpreting as the `Z` argument. But you have two other issues.

1. `Y` needs to be converted to a numeric type, which you can do by changing the `y` definition to `y = df.columns.astype(float)`.
2. `Z` is the transpose of what it should be, but that can be fixed by doing `Z = df.values.T`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'10.2': [72,57,56,67,69,136], 
        '10.6':[31,23,19,17,41,74],
        '10.9': [27,96,97,99,18,40], 
        '11.3':[10,98,100,35,67,258], 
        '11.8':[124,92,49,24,88,209]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df.index
y = df.columns.astype(float)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = df.values.T
c = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]

Comment: @ARINDAMDAS If this solution works then you can click the gray check button next to my answer to accept it.

Comment: When the index  of the dataframe is changed to datetime index, the same code is not working is giving error " TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. I have triesd with .tolist() but it gives the same error @ jared

Comment: @ARINDAMDAS That's a new error, not the same error. I can't help without seeing the code. If you can't find the answer on SO, then post a new question.